# How can I add the value I created from user input and transfer that to a LinkedList?

Tags: java

Below is the following code I have created. My question is how can I create a method that returns a value created from user input and then place that value at the end of my LinkedList? For example the computer will prompt me to enter the char 'a' to add another client. How can I create a method that stores that added client information in the LinkedList?

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

    public class Clients implements Serializable
    {   
        private LinkedList<Person> clients = new LinkedList<Person>();
        private int id = 1;

        private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static String nextLine()
        {   
            return in.nextLine(); 
        }

        public static char nextChar()
        {   
            return in.nextLine().charAt(0); 
        }

        public Clients()
        {   
            clients.add(new Person("Homer", id++));
            clients.add(new Person("Marge", id++));   
        }

        public void addClients()
        {
            //??????????
            //????????????
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am not missing anything, and no validation of input I think it would be something like:

```
clients.add(new Person(nextLine(), id++);
```